# Указатели, массивы, функции. Обработка массива

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Функция уменьшения каждого элемента массива на значение первого элемента. На входе массив и его длина.
Срабатывает только для первого элемента

```
void romdomdom(double * firstel,int * otrlen){
    double *rovn=firstel;
    for(int i=0;i<*otrlen;i++){
        *(firstel+i)=*(firstel+i)-*rovn;
    }
}
```

Всё работает если сделать так, с созданием переменой

```
void romdomdom(double * firstel,int * otrlen){
    double rovn=*firstel;
    for(int i=0;i<*otrlen;i++){
        *(firstel+i)=*(firstel+i)-rovn;
    }
}
```

непонятно почему не работает первый вариант только через указатели.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Она вообще не может работать -

```
for(int i;i<*otrlen;i++)
```

ведь начальное значение `i` не установлено!

Напишите

```
for(int i = 0; i < *otrlen; i++)
```

И еще - во втором случае вы **запоминаете** первое значение и вычитаете это *запомненное* значение, которое было *до изменений*.

А во втором - просто обнуляете первый элемент, а потом этот ноль на месте первого элемента вычитаете из всех остальных...

Workaround: :)

```
for(int i = *otrlen-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Comment: писал по памяти i=0 забыл, оно там было, поправлю вопрос